# Swift Scenekit show image on basic plane

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

My goal is to have an app where I can scan a certain image and display an AR-Generated Model next to it. I am following this [project](https://www.appcoda.com/arkit-image-recognition/).

I already imported the image I want to scan and that is working as expected. The problem now is to import my own Model. And that is where I struggle.

What I want is to display a 2D Image on a simple PlaneScene on top or next to the detected image.

I managed to create a `.dae` file from Blender. I also imported it into Xcode and converted it inside XCode to a `.scn` file.

This is how it looks:

[image]

As you can see the image is not correctly displayed.. It is just white. Also when running the app, the Object is not being displayed. I can not see it anywhere, but it is also not throwing an error.

This is my `.dae` file: [File](https://gofile.io/d/DpHVyW)

Maybe I dont even need Blender for that but I couldn't find a way to display an image onto a Plane in XCode...

What am I missing here? I feel like there is something wrong with my Model. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, when I open your file in Blender and go to the Front view:

[image: your plane object]

Your Plane is wrong oriented in the space. One looks at it from the side and it is not well centered. (but this is probably what you want).

But you don't need an imported geometry object. Apple has a solution to this.

I recommend you to use the built in plane (SCNPlane, what is a SCNGeometry object) for your project. It will have a front view oriantation by default and you can easely move the offset position.

Let me know if you need an example. But it should be easy to find out how to do this.

PS: If you want to import Models this here is a useful extension to do this:

```
extension SCNNode {
    convenience init(named name: String) {
        self.init()
        guard let scene = SCNScene(named: name) else {return}
        for childNode in scene.rootNode.childNodes {addChildNode(childNode)}
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to add some `depth` in Xcode to the plane? I guess it wouldn't be a plane anymore but basically a box with an image on the front

Comment: You can use the built in SCNBox. But note, you will have your image displayed on all six faces by default. You could make a combination of a SCNPlane and a SCNBox, placing the plane a tiny little bit above the Box, to avoid z-Fighting.

Comment: I feel like it would be easier so just add the Model from Blender

Comment: Do you know how to easily import a file? I coulndt make it work..

Comment: Make sure in Blender, when you go to the front view, everything is oriented and placed the way you want. then Apply all transforms in Blender. Then export the Model as DAE or OBJ. Import in XCode and if you want you can convert it to SCN, but no need, you can use the models directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243499/discussion-between-chris-and-zay).